# AjaxControlToolkit not working after publish. ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, publish

I am writing an application in Visual Studio 2010 using ASP.net and C#. I'm using the AjaxControlToolkit which I installed through Nuget, and it works perfectly when testing on my local machine. My question is, when I publish the website online to our server, ajax doesn't work. (Two pictures below. Couldn't post them in here since I'm a new user, but I've got the photobucket links. Ignore the album name, it was a friend's band name..Haha.)

This is a picture of what it looks like when I test it on my local computer. Notice the MaskedEditExtender in the "Phone Number" text box, and how the Navigation bar up top looks; normal. (http://i16.photobucket.com/albums/b25/MenOpause_is_awesome/Page1.png)

This is how it looks when I publish it online. The MaskedEditExtenders don't work in the "Phone Number" textbox anymore, and my Navigation bar is all messed up for some reason. (http://i16.photobucket.com/albums/b25/MenOpause_is_awesome/Page2-1.png)

I've uploaded my project manually and still it yields the same results when using AjaxControlToolkit. Taking Ajax out entirely, it looks fine on my local machine and on the published website; I just don't have all the Ajax validations that I would really like to use. I can provide you with my code if needed, but it seems like I'm just missing some directory or file in the upload process, or something just isn't working or not set up right. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced and let me know if there's any other information I can provide if you might know the reason.

EDIT (SOLVED): I added the following line to my web.config, which fixed everything apparently and had it working online:

```
 <handlers>
  <remove name="AXD-ISAPI-4.0-64" />
  <remove name="AXD-ISAPI-4.0" />
  <remove name="AboMapperCustom-27080" />
  <remove name="AboMapperCustom-27079" />
  <remove name="AboMapperCustom-27078" />
  <remove name="AboMapperCustom-27077" />
  <remove name="AboMapperCustom-27076" />
  <remove name="AboMapperCustom-27075" />
  <remove name="AboMapperCustom-27074" />
  <remove name="AboMapperCustom-27073" />
  <remove name="AboMapperCustom-27072" />
  <remove name="AboMapperCustom-27062" />
  <add name="AXD-ISAPI-4.0" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
  <add name="AXD-ISAPI-4.0-64" path="*.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
  <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />

</handlers>
```

Comment: Are the .net Framework versions both the same on your local machine a server?

Comment: Also, how are you publishing it? Are you just copying files over or are you actually rebuilding it on the server?

Comment: I believe both Framework versions are .net 4. I tried manually copying the files over without building it, building it and copying the files over manually and I tried rebuilding it then publishing it though Visual Studio.

Comment: If you can get on the server or the wherever you're publishing the site, please ensure that .NEt 4.0 is in fact installed on it. Check the following path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework

Comment: It is installed on it and on mine too, I just checked. I'm not too knowledgeable with that stuff in particular, but I just double checked. Maybe something didn't transfer properly?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Check the bin file on the server and make sure you see an ajax dll there.

Comment: Also, check your assemblies in your web config files. They also must show Version 4.0

Comment: No, I haven't figured it out yet, I don't see any assemblies in my webconfig, maybe that's the problem? I just figured installing it through Nuget would install everything I need.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm leaving work at Noon (EST), and won't be able to continue working on this until next Monday. I don't want you to feel like you need to be on her come Monday, but if you happen to scroll by here and have nothing else to do, I'd really appreciate to continue the conversation. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare both config files and make sure they match, except of course where they should differ in connection  strings depending on if you're using some type of development DB.

You'll probably see an assemblies tag on the web config file on your local machine and that needs to be also on your web config file on the production server.

**Your assemblies would look something like this:**

```
<assemblies>    
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
</assemblies>
```

Comment: I have no assemblies line in my webconfig file for some reason? Do you have any idea what I'd need to write down to add it?

Comment: Ok, so I was able to find out what the problem was. I had to add a line under handlers in the webconfig file. I can show you what I added if you're curious, but the problem is fixed now! I appreciate your help a lot! I remade the app starting fresh, and it automatically added the assemblies you put above when I reinstalled Ajax Control Toolkit, although those where there in previous test versions of the app. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, and no problem. And if you will, I'd like to see what line fixed the problem. Maybe you can post it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat of a guess, but if it's not in web.config and not in the code, it could be a mismatch of items in the bin directory.

I use the ajax framweork, and my bin directory has all these resource dlls.

[image]

Comment: My bin has all of those included in the project, but I've got nothing in the webconfig except for controls. Any other ideas?