# Getting Error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am getting this error when i upload my website on server.Even though when I run it on local server in visual studio it works fine.Please help me to solve this issue.I am using visual studio 2012 with sql server 2008 .Also there is a packages folder outside project folder, may be I need to upload dat too..Please help

**The error** I am getting :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

    Exception Details: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

    Source Error: 


    Line 96:          
    Line 97: 
    Line 98:         <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    Line 99:      
    Line 100:<header>

    Source File: g:\pleskvhosts\hitchtechnologies.com\manshasweets.hitchtechnologies.com\MasterPage.master    Line: 98 

    Stack Trace: 


    [ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
       System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
       System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() +4
       System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +61
       AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerConfig..cctor() in ToolkitScriptManagerConfig.cs:32

    [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerConfig' threw an exception.]
       AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager..ctor() in ToolkitScriptManager.cs:114
       ASP.masterpage_master.__BuildControlToolkitScriptManager1() in g:\pleskvhosts\hitchtechnologies.com\manshasweets.hitchtechnologies.com\MasterPage.master:98
       ASP.masterpage_master.__BuildControlform1() in g:\pleskvhosts\hitchtechnologies.com\manshasweets.hitchtechnologies.com\MasterPage.master:93
       ASP.masterpage_master.__BuildControlTree(masterpage_master __ctrl) in g:\pleskvhosts\hitchtechnologies.com\manshasweets.hitchtechnologies.com\MasterPage.master:1
       ASP.masterpage_master.FrameworkInitialize() in g:\pleskvhosts\hitchtechnologies.com\manshasweets.hitchtechnologies.com\MasterPage.master.cs:912308
       System.Web.UI.UserControl.InitializeAsUserControlInternal() +32
       System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) +655
       System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() +54
       System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() +14
       System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +45
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +335

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18056
```

this is my web.config.please help me if i have done ne thing wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="connectionString" value="Data Source=Node-6-PC;Initial Catalog=dbMansha;user id=sa; password=hitch@123;"/>

    <add key="SiteFileFolder" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="129600" />
    <globalization culture="en-GB"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">

    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="12000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" executionTimeout="45"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">

      <forms timeout="129600"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: try uploading another mock application to the server which uses ajax control toolkit, and verify if that works or not...

Comment: It is giving me same error.

Comment: You web.config should have entries as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9231867/145682 They should appear by itself if on the design mode you drag the toolscriptmanager on to the aspx page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to change ajax 4.5 to 4.0. and worked.

Answer (score 3):

Just put

```xml
<system.web>
  <trust level="Full" />
```